# Webassembly output from Unity doesn't launch in IOS 12.x versions

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, webassembly

I have developed a game in Unity and output is WASM. 
I am aware WASM is not fully supported by mobile browsers. However on Android browsers all works well.
I have a big issue when running the game on Safari in an iPhone running any 12.x iOS versions.
Its stops at the launch screen itself.
What could be the issue and potential solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: It would be nice if you can post the error logs or any other useful information. We can't answer at this type of questions

Comment: You're aware that it's not fully supported by mobile browsers and yet have an issue running it on a mobile browser? Gosh, I wonder why. (Sorry for the sarcasm, but you answered your own question there; what do you honestly expect us to be able to do?).